# error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 504.00 KiB/s

Tags: heroku

I have a problem with git push.
Its not working

```
Counting objects: 143, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (116/116), done.
error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 504.00 KiB/s    
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly| 11.00 KiB/s   
Writing objects: 100% (120/120), 207.69 MiB | 7.03 MiB/s, done.
Total 120 (delta 32), reused 0 (delta 0)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

It's not working can someone help me in this it took so much time to to push and after that it give me this result.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your terminal just misprinted some characters. The actual error is:

```
error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 504
```

HTTP 504 means the server timed out. Searching for this should find you better help!